# CONCATENATE rows with character for range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have a pretty long list of numbers that I would like to concatenate for a regex like this:

```
2323
2352
3432
…

2323|2352|3432
```

Now, I can obviously use the `CONCATENATE` function, but it would still require me to enter each row individually like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, "|", A2, …)
```

Is there any way to apply a range together with the splitting character?

Comment: Do you have [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)? Available in Excel 2019 and O365.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is a job for [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c), available in Excel 2019 and O365.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,A1:A3)
```